# Nginx locations configuration

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have config

```
location ~ \.(pdf)$ {
    expires 2h;
}

location / {
    ...backend rules...
}
```

Now I want the first block to be executed only for really existing pdfs, otherwise the request would be passed to the backend.
I suppose I should add in the first location block `try_files $uri @backend`:

```
location ~ \.(pdf)$ {
    try_files $uri @backend;
    expires 2h;
}

location / {
    ...backend rules...
}

location @backend {
    ...same backend rules...
}
```

But it turns out that both locations `/` and `@backend` will be absolutely identical, is there any way to combine them or should I just make two identical blocks?

Comment: Put backend rules to separate file and use `include`.

Comment: A separate file is an idea, but I don't want to add complexity with an additional file. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can shorten your `location` to

```
location / {
    try_files "" @backend;
}
```

This will produce an extra system `stat` call for every request, but since it is your web root directory that will be `stat`'ed, those calls should be some kind of cached by the kernel and it should not be a serious performance impact.

PS

You don't need a capture group for your regex location, just `location ~ \.pdf$ { ... }` will be enough (yet slightly more performant).

**Update**

One more suggestion that would allow to reduce the number of locations:

```
map $uri $try {
    ~\.pdf$                                 $uri;
    <some_other_mask_to_try_locally_first>  $uri;
    # default value will be an empty string
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $try @backend;
    }
    location @backend {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas here and on SO. On the brackets - of course, while simplifying the config for the question I forgot to remove them)

Comment: Check the answer update.